# How to detect new apps in an Android device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, contentobserver, android-package-managers

I want to detect when the user installs or deletes an app, and I didn't find a `BroadcastReceiver` that does this.

In my app, I get the information about the installed apps with the class `PackageManager`, but I don't want to scan the apps periodically. Is there any `BroadcastReceiver` that does this? Or any `ContentObserver`? Is it possible to get a notification that an app has been installed or removed?

Comment: I believe the answer is _no_ ...

Comment: It appears I was wrong, :-), I had forgotten that one!

Comment: If you are feeling ambitious, you should take a look at the `AsyncTaskLoader` class... implementing your own `Loader` here would be a damn good learning experience in my opinion :P

Comment: The [**sample code**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) in the docs actually does exactly what you describe (or at least I believe it does, from the looks of it). Check it out!

Comment: Thank you for all. I don't know how I will do it, but I want to upload the data to a server when the app list change, without requiring the app be running at that moment, so I think I will do it with a service, Is it the best way to do? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` using `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` (and also  `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` and/or `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED` if necessary). For instance,

```
void registerReceiver() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
    filter.addDataScheme("package_name");     
}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)) {
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        String pkgName = data.getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();
    }

    /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: I think that `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED` do the same that `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` and `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`, no?

Comment: No. You can check from this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

Comment: Thanks I was looking for 'getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart' I had expected it to be getHost I needed but the lack of // in the uri broke that...